# Yii refresh Tab data on Tab Active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I am working on Yii application and using Tabs to show chart and data.
my code is as bellow

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab-graph” data-toggle="tab">
             <?php echo Yii::t('li', ‘Graph’);?>
               </a>
             </li>
              <li>
               <a href="#tab-overview" data-toggle="tab">
                 <?php echo Yii::t('li', ‘Overview');?>
                  </a>
                    </li>
              </ul>


<div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-graph">
  <?php
  $this->renderPartial(‘graph/graph’);
  ?>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab-overview">
  <div> here is status</div>
  <div> 10%</div>
</div>

</div>
```

in first tabe i am renderPartial the file which show YII graph, but the issue is when i click on next tab and come back to first tab, graph dissappear.

i think YII graph did't like tabs and hide.

how to make the graph active on first tab when click away and come back ?
or
i want to refresh the tab and render again to show graph.

```
<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var target = $(e.target).attr("href")

  if(target=="#tab-graph"){
    //alert(target);
    location.reload();
  }
});
</script>
```

i have done this uing jquery but this refresh all page, but i only need to show graph or only refresh the tab not all page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can update your tab data using ajax request. Set an ajax call on click on tab. And use renderPartial('view', false, true). 
[Examples here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply but  how to do renderPartial in Javascript ? the  i try this $.get('graph/graph', null, function(html) but its not working, its showing me wrong path and can't load file.